# CFile + WriteHuge not working

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, mfc, visual-c++

HI,
I am using CFIle in my application and when i compiled my code i am getting error
'WriteHuge' : is not a member of 'CFile'
'ReadHuge' : is not a member of 'CFile'

I included

```
    #include "afx.h" 
    CFile file;
    file.WriteHuge(m_pDib,bmpFileHeader.bfSize-nBmpFileHeaderSize);
    file.ReadHuge(m_pDib,bmpFileHeader.bfSize-nBmpFileHeaderSize);
```

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those functions don't exist in newer versions of MFC.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5sweaay3%28VS.80%29.aspx